# How can I imprint the 5 cubes on a curved surface

Tags: modifiers

How can I imprint the 5 cubes on a curved surface? I'm looking for a 1mm imprint. to mark as windows.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Best method in your case would be:

1. Create planes and add an array modifier
2. Add shrinkwrap modifier to attach the planes to the surface with 1mm offset.
3. Add solidify modifier to add depth to the planes.

Potentially add bevel, smooth for nice effects and maybe boolean subtract.

Otherwise in the more general case for complex meshes, you could shrinkwrap but limit to specific vertex groups, or manually with "Snap to Faces" turned on.

Comment: How do I position the 5 windows on the surface?.. Equally

Comment: Position the windows equally on the surface before the shrinkwrap.